# Can't enable and focus input at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an input that will be disabled by default, but at the click of a button I would like to simultaneously enable and focus the input.

I have attempted this in the same function, however it doesn't seem to work in my IDE/local react environment, and requires **clicking the button twice to do this** once will enable the input and the second will focus it... It is very strange to me

[image]

**App.jsx**

```
export const MyConstant = () => {
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
    const myInput = useRef();

    const enableAndFocus = () => {
        setIsDisabled(false);
        myInput.current.focus();
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => enableAndFocus()}>ClickMe</button>

        <input ref={myInput} disabled={isDisabled} />
    )
}
```

[Here is a stackblitz of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enable-and-focus-input?file=src/App.js)

I can't understand why it won't do them together... Is it because the state change is slower than the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setIsDisabled` is async function so when `myInput.current.focus()` executes your input is still disabled.

To fix this try to use `useEffect` hook like below:-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isDisabled) {
      myInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isDisabled]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with React, but I guess you can do a little trick like this, to allow React to "digest" the enabled state before focusing the input :

```
const enableAndFocus = async () => {
        setIsDisabled(false);
        await Promise.resolve();
        myInput.current.focus();
}
```

Comment: Ah! Looks like a variation on this worked. Instead of the `await Promise.resolve()` I simply added the `await` before `setIsDisabled` as that is the async part of the function. Why didn't I think of this before?!

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `useEffect` hook which is listening for the `isDisabled` change and then you can focus on the input inside the hook if the `isDisabled` is false.

```
export const MyConstant = () => {
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
    const myInput = useRef();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        !isDisabled && myInput.current.focus();
    }, [isDisabled])

    const enableAndFocus = () => {
        setIsDisabled(false);
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => enableAndFocus()}>ClickMe</button>

        <input ref={myInput} disabled={isDisabled} />
    )
}
```